# Vectorized reshaping of matrix by blocks

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization, reshape

I have this matrix

```
[1,2,3;
 4,5,6;
 7,8,9;
 10,11,12;]
```

I want to reshape it in block of 2,  stack rows in multiples of 2. So the output would look like

```
[1,2,3,7,8,9;
 4,5,6,10,11,12]
```

In general I want to reshape it in `(N^2) x M` matrix to `N x (N*M)` matrix in blocks. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple enough, assuming `A` as the input matrix -

```
reshape(permute(reshape(A,N,N,[]),[1 3 2 4]),N,[])
```

Comment: Hmm... does `permute(M,[1,3,2,4])` differ from `permute(M,[1,3,2])` for a 3d matrix `M`?

Comment: @AndrasDeak No same thing. I was in too hurry to post and it skipped my mind I guess :) Well Daniel posted with that and I thought we both could keep our answers, but he deleted his.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks :)

Comment: Is there something which works for sparse matrices too? Matlab doesn't support permutation of N-D sparse arrays

Comment: @Rahul: You probably have to do it manually, which means "unpack" the nonzero elements form your matrix using `[x,y]=find(A);e=nonzero(A)`, then modify x and y and finally recreate the sparse matrix, but I think it will be a slow operation.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Divakar is not happy unless he uses 4 dimensions at least